# enable TLSv1.2 in httpclient

Tags: java, ssl, jetty, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-commons-httpclient

Google says, by default TLS 1 is enabled for http client and we have to enable TLSv1.2 ourself to use it. Can anyone tell me how to do it?

I am using Jetty as server and enabled TLSv1.2 protocol on it.

I am using httpClient 4.4.1

On my client, i have done:

```
sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom()
                .loadTrustMaterial(trustStore, null)
               .loadKeyMaterial(client_key_store, "password".toCharArray())
               .useProtocol("TLSv1.2")
                .build();

 SSLConnectionSocketFactory factory=new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslcontext, new String[]{"TLSv1.2"},sslcontext..getDefaultSSLParameters().getCipherSuites(), SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getDefaultHostnameVerifier());

 try (CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(factory).build()) {
                HttpGet req = new HttpGet("https://localhost:8443/");
                System.out.println("executing request" + req.getRequestLine());


            try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(req)) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                System.out.println("*** Reponse status:" + response.getStatusLine());
                EntityUtils.consume(entity);
                System.out.println("*** Response entity: "+ entity.toString());
            }
        }
```

Then i have excluded all those ciphersuites ( which i got using

```
sslcontext.getDefaultSSLParameters().getCipherSuites()
```

on client ) except "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256" on jetty server , it gave me error. [I need this ciphersuite. Java says it is implemented in tLSv1.2 in JAVA7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html)

```
<Set name="ExcludeCipherSuites">
        <Array type="java.lang.String">
           <Item>...</Item>

                  <!--
            <Item>TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256</Item>
              -->
            </Array>
      </Set>
```

Comment: Google is probably wrong or out of date. Try the actual current documentation.